# Why do I need "c" infront of class name in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class names that start with C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292468/class-names-that-start-with-c)

I am a newbie using c++ and people named c++ class name "c"+something. What does that mean? I think this is a syntax but don't know what it means..

Comment: because c is for cookie. (and that's good enough for me)

Comment: Convention only - another is to use underscore_t for types (maybe including classes), as with some standard types such as `std::size_t`.

Comment: See the other comment and answers below.  The Borland tools used "T" (presumably for "type) rather than "C".  It's interesting to me that "I" is still used as a prefix to denote interfaces in .NET today.

Comment: @Steve314 - the _t comes from C and I believe it's supposed to denote `typedef`s.

Comment: @David: the `_t` is reserved for POSIX typedefs, and is best avoided in other C and C++ usage.

Comment: @Tony - The C++ standard doesn't reserve anything for Posix AFAIK ;-) - seriously, _t used in the C++ standard library which is not Posix - "best avoided" can't be that strict. And a lot of C++ programmers have never programmed for Posix, and have no reason to know anything about it.

Comment: @David - Interesting point, but the problem with easily misunderstood conventions (ie my excuse) is that they can easily trigger alternative conventions consistent with the misunderstanding. Also (my second excuse), _t is found as a convention for types in some non-C-family languages. I probably saw it in Pascal first, which IIRC doesn't have any type alias declarations. I've certainly seen it in Ada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not needed by C++, but some people do it to remind them that the identifier is for a class.  It's considered bad practice now, but was popular (especially in Microsoft environments) a decade or more ago.

Answer (score 9):

you don't. it's a naming convention only: http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices (see Hungarian)